# Holy Reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reflection

I'm receiving an error, *"unable to convert string to int?"*.  Which I find odd, I was under the notion when you utilize `PropertyInfo.SetValue` it should indeed attempt to use that fields type.

```
// Sample:
property.SetValue(model, null, null);
```

The above would attempt to implement `default(T)` on the property according to `PropertyInfo.SetValue` for the Microsoft Developer Network.  However, when I implement the following code:

```
// Sample:
property.SetValue(model, control.Value, null);
```

The error bubbles, when I implement a `string` for a property that should have an `int?`, I was under the notion that it would attempt to automatically resolve the specified type.  How would I help specify the type?

```
// Sample:
PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(TModel).GetProperties();
foreach(var property in properties)
     if(typeof(TModel).Name.Contains("Sample"))
          property.SetValue(model, control.Value, null);
```

Any clarification and how to resolve the cast would be helpful.  The sample has been  modified for brevity, trying to provide relevant code.

Comment: if control.Value is string you need to convert it to type of the property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to convert the control value to the type which the property is using [`Convert.ChangeType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130977.aspx):

```
if(typeof(TModel).Name.Contains("Sample"))  
   property.SetValue(model, Convert.ChangeType(control.Value, property.PropertyType), null);
```

### UPDATE:

In your case it is `Nullable` type (`Nullable<int>`) so you have to do it different way as `Convert.ChangeType()` in normal not works on Nullable types:

```
if(typeof(TModel).Name.Contains("Sample"))
{ 
  if (property.PropertyType.IsGenericType && property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
  {
     property.SetValue(model,Convert.ChangeType(control.Value, property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0]),null);
  }
  else
  {
    property.SetValue(model, Convert.ChangeType(control.Value, property.PropertyType), null);
  }
```

Comment: The only problem with that, it does `InvalidCastException` "Invalid Cast from System.String to System.Nullable.Int32"

Comment: ok @Greg you have Nullable type you have to do different way for it, i have updated my answer as well

Comment: Will that handle all types though, `decimal?`, `bool?` or only `int?`?

Comment: yes it will , you can see we have not hardcoded any type we pick at runtime the type of property

Comment: Do I have a typo then, cause I receive this when it encounters a `decimal?` An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: and what's the value of ``control.Value`` at that time?

Comment: The value is `"13.4500000000"`  I might be an idiot.

Comment: what is the variable ``model`` here?

Comment: Just checked that, it appears to be an `int?`.  Why the database has it as an `int` is beyond me.

Comment: @Greg i have just tested it with the value you said it works fine

Comment: Weird, you've been a tremendous help.I'll try and figure it out.

Comment: pleasure it helped you ..:)